# Ruby1.8 Rails2.3 ./script/server producing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been assigned a projected that was written in Ruby1.8 and Rails2.3. We can't upgrade at the moment. I have successfully installed ruby and rails and installed all needed gems for the project on a ubuntu machine. I have received success messages while installing everything.

However, when I run the command ./script/server I received the output:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require': no such file to load -- sentry (MissingSourceFile)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    from /home/robotmaster/Documents/Source/agile/config/initializers/sentry.rb:1
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:171:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:171:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:171:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/initializer.rb:622:in `load_application_initializers'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `load_application_initializers'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/initializer.rb:176:in `process'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /home/robotmaster/Documents/Source/agile/config/environment.rb:42
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/commands/server.rb:84
    from ./script/server:4:in `require'
    from ./script/server:4
```

I am new to the Rails and would appreciate any help with this error message. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The key to the issue is here:

```
sentry (MissingSourceFile)
```

I'm really not familiar with that particular file (and Rail 2.3 is several major revisions behind...) but it indicates to me that there's something incomplete about your Gem set.

```
gem update
```

This would be my first attempt.  Verify that all of the referenced gems in your Gemfile are present on the system.  If at all possible, I'd really look to upgrade to at least Rail 3, preferably 4.

EDIT:

Reading this again, why are you executing ./script/server?  You should be executing:

```
rails s
```